# Nusoap retorno $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA vazio

Tags: php, web-service

Estou tentando criar um WebService utilizando o **nusooap**. Porém o meu retorno é sempre vazio. Online é criado o webService e eu consigo ver os métodos e o xml (WSDL). Mas ao tentar acessar via `cliente.php` o retorno é vázio.

**teste-server.php**

```
require_once "php/class/nusoap-0.9.5/lib/nusoap.php";

$soap = new soap_server;

  $soap->configureWSDL('WS-WebCodeFree', 'http://www.philipsvaloriza.com.br/teste-server.php');

  $soap->wsdl->schemaTargetNamespace = 'http://www.philipsvaloriza.com.br/teste-server.php';

    $soap->register(
        'info',
        array(),
        array('x' => 'xsd:string'),
        'http://soapinterop.org/'
    );

    $soap->register(
        'post_java',
        array(),
        array('x' => 'xsd:string'),
        'http://soapinterop.org/'
    );

    $soap->register(
        'post_php',
        array(),
        array('x' => 'xsd:string'),
        'http://soapinterop.org/'
    );

    $soap->register(
        'login_user',
        array('login' => 'xsd:string','pass' => 'xsd:int'),
        array('x' => 'xsd:string'),
        'http://soapinterop.org/'
    );

$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : 'teste123';
$soap->service(isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '');

function info(){
    return "WebCodeFree - Desenvolvimento Web.";
}

function post_java(){
    return "Em Breve Acesso a Postagens Java Via Serviço";
}

function post_php(){
    return "Em Breve Acesso a Postagens PHP Via Serviço";
}

function login_user($login, $senha){
    return "Seja Bem Vindo Usuário ". $login . " !!!";
}
```

**cliente.php**

```
include('lib/nusoap.php');


        $cliente = new nusoap_client('http://localhost/vinicius/thiengo/doc/projects/web-service-php-nusoap/servidor.php?wsdl');


    $result1 = $client->call('info');

    $result2 = $client->call('post_java');

    $result3 = $client->call('post_php');

    $result4 = $client->call('login_user', array('Paulo',12));

    echo $result1."<br>";
    echo $result2."<br>";
    echo $result3."<br>";
    echo $result4."<br>";
```

**Referência:** http://www.webcodefree.com.br/blog/?p=1480

Comment: Qual éa versão do php? 5.6?

Comment: Sim @rray o servidor está utilizando o PHP 5.6

Answer (score 1):

O uso de [$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA](http://us.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php) é obsoleto desde o php5.6 e removido no php7. Em seu lugar use:

```
$info = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Comment: Eu subistitui o "$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : 'teste123';
$soap->service(isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '');" por "$postData = file_get_contents('php://input'); $soap->service(isset($postData));". Mas o retorno continua vázio. Sabe me dizer se a forma de utilizar a classe nusoap tb muda?

Comment: @alan tira esse `isset()` de `$soap->service(isset($postData))`

Comment: Eu retirei. E mesmo assim o retorno continua vázio. Também criei um arquivo no servidor: "$file = fopen('arquivo.txt', 'w');
fwrite($file, $postData);" e ele criou o arquivo em branco. Por algum motivo a variável $postData não está recebendo valor.

Comment: @alan tentou fazer a chamada com soup_client (nativo) do php?

Comment: Não. fiz os testes apenas com nusoop_client. Vou fazer um teste.